# How to hook into Soft keyboard 'showing' and 'hiding' events in a WPF application running on Windows 10 (tablet)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uwp, winui-3

I have an Ionic / Cordova application hosted in the Windows UWP application, and which I am looking into swapping to host within a **WPF** application (latest .net, eg 6.0), and using WebView2.

Note, the Ionic/Cordova part is not really relevant to this question, this is purely related to **WPF**.

When running on a **Tablet** (eg Microsoft surface), I need to resize the app when the **soft keyboard** is shown, and hidden.

When in **UWP**, I could hook into the following events in my TypeScript file...

```
  let w = <any>window;
  const inputPane = w.Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.getForCurrentView();
  if (!inputPane) {
    this.logger.error('WindowsKeyboardService.hookupKeyboardHandlers: could not get inputPane');
    return;
  }

  inputPane.addEventListener('showing', _ => this.onWindowsKeyboardUp);
  inputPane.addEventListener('hiding', _ => this.onWindowsKeyboardClose);
```

So I won't have the WinJS any longer in the WPF, so I will do all the native in the WPF and then call into the JS myself using the appropriate API on the webview.

If I was in **UWP**, I could do something like the following:

```
System.Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Showing += (s, args) =>
  {
    GeneralTransform gt = loginButton.TransformToVisual(this);
    Point buttonPoint = gt.TransformPoint(new Point(0, loginButton.RenderSize.Height - 1));
    var trans = new TranslateTransform { Y = -(buttonPoint.Y - args.OccludedRect.Top) };
    loginButton.RenderTransform = trans;
    args.EnsuredFocusedElementInView = true;
  };
```

But in WPF, I do not seem to have the `System.Windows.UI namespace:

[image]

Is there an equivalent way of doing this within a **WPF** application?

### Update 1

I found [this sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/master/Input%20and%20Commands/TouchKeyboard/TouchKeyboardNotifier)

The whole solution will build in .net framework (4.7), but not in .net 6, as still missing the namespace `Windows.UI`. Perhaps this is renamed to something?

### Update 2

I create a new **WinUI** project. Calling

```
var pane = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView();
```

gives the same `Element Not found` error. I call this in a button click event, to give the main app/Window plenty of time to be fully initialized.

Note I am trying this out running from Visual Studio (i.e. Desktop Windows 10), and not on an actual tablet at this stage.

I [this similar post](https://issueexplorer.com/issue/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/1414) where there is a comment

> @LeftTwixWand ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView and CoreApplication.GetCurrentView() are only for UWP apps. For WinUI 3 desktop apps, use the Window class for some of the functionality. I'm not completely sure but some of them also now a GetForWindowId method.

It mentions using the `Window` class, but there is nothing on how to do what I am after here (monitoring the soft keyboard show/hide events).

### Update 3

Following @Victor below, I added the code and it asks me to install

[image]

@Victor is this correct?

Comment: To access WinRT API in .NET 6, you need to set `<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.22000.0</TargetFramework>` . See [Call Windows Runtime APIs in desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance).  In addition, you may need to add `System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime` from nuget.

Comment: @emoacht thanks for that, looked promising. I added the above, and now I can access `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView();`. Unfortunately it is gives me a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Element not found. (0x80070490)'`, so currently searching for why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

For WPF you just need to use net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0 target framework or newer. APIs will be available for you via existing Interop classes. Do not use System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime, it is .net framework approach.

```
IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
InputPane inputPane = InputPaneInterop.GetForWindow(handle);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've added a comment to the main question as Update 3 so could include a screen shot

Comment: You probably miss '<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0</TargetFramework>' or you are not using Microsoft.NET.Sdk with <UseWpf>true</UseWpf> it should come with SDK. No need for additional packages in the pure WPF project. But I do not know your case.

Comment: I updated my target OS and now the above code will compile. But when I run it I get the exception `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070490): Element not found. (0x80070490)` at the line `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView()`